How to show $\textrm{Uniform}(1/\theta, \theta+1/\theta) $ doesn't have stochastic order?
In this paper, the authors proposed an example of $\textrm{Uniform}(1/\theta, \theta+1/\theta) $ to show that $\theta_1<\theta_2$ doesn't imply the mles $\hat{\theta}_1\overset{\textrm{st}}{\leq}\hat\theta_2$ (for $n=1$).

[...] However, it can be shown that the usual stochastic order does not hold between $\hat\theta_1$ and $\hat\theta_2$ if $1<\theta_1<\theta_2$  since it does not hold between $X $ and $Y.$

Here $X\sim\textrm{Uniform}(1/\theta_1, \theta_1+1/\theta_1) $ and $Y\sim\textrm{Uniform}(1/\theta_2, \theta_2+1/\theta_2) .$
If the authors are to go by, then $\hat{\theta}_1\overset{\textrm{st}}{\leq}\hat\theta_2$ fails because $X\overset{\textrm{st}}{\leq}Y$ fails.
That means there should exist a $t$ such that $\Pr(X> t) \leq \Pr(Y>t) $ doesn't hold.
What should be the approach to show that? Brute force to find such $t$? Or is there any better way?

So the authors are dealing with the proposition $$\lbrace X_1 \overset{\textrm{st}}{\leq} X_2 , \forall ,\theta_1 < \theta_2 \rbrace \implies \hat{\theta}(X_1) \overset{\textrm{st}}{\leq}\hat\theta(X_2)$$
and are using an example where $X_1 \overset{\textrm{st}}{\leq} X_2$ is not the case?

Partly. They are more interested in if $\theta_1<\theta_2, $ whether $\hat\theta_1\overset{\text{st}}{\leq}\theta_2$ holds. In the example it doesn't hold for as they said the stochastic order doesn't hold for $X$ and $Y$ either.

i see now what they meant with 'preserving order'.

If you take two examples $\theta_1 = 1$ and $\theta_2 =2$, then
$$\begin{array}{}
X \sim U(1,2) \\
Y \sim U(0.5,2.5)
\end{array}$$
which have cumulative distribution functions that cross.
So while we have $\theta_2>\theta_1$, we do not have $Y \overset{\textrm{st}}{\leq} X$, and neither $X \overset{\textrm{st}}{\leq} Y$. So the same will be true for the estimates $1/X$ and $1/Y$ (which would preserve stochastic order because they are monotonic transformations, or reverse the equality from $\leq$ to $>$, because it flips the order)

What should be the approach to show that? Brute force to find such t
? Or is there any better way?

I plotted first the boundaries of the uniform distributions as a function of $\theta$, to see cases with overlap.
You can imagine/plot the cumulative distribution function of overlapping uniform distributions and see that they cross (which means that neither is stochastically dominant).


An easier example would be with a different parameterisation
$$X\sim U(\theta, \theta +1/\theta) \\
Y\sim U(\theta, \theta +1/\theta)$$
such that the mle is the identity function $\hat{\theta}_1 = X$ and $\hat{\theta}_2 = Y$

I haven't read the article yet, but it seems like the condition for preserving order is that the quantile functions of the sample distribution of the mle, need to be monotonically increasing functions of the parameter. I guess that such a way to look at it is very intuitive.

The crossing. Yes, that would do. Couldn't get why the authors wanted values of $\theta> 1$ for it seems to be working here. Also, re the example you stated, what are the bounds about? Otherwise +1.

@User1865345 The distribution is uniform between two bounds $U(l(\theta), u(\theta))$ where the bounds depend on $\theta$. Those two bounds are plotted in the graph. You could see it as the 0-th percentile and 100-th percentile of the sample distribution of the mle as function of $\theta$ and for preserving the order those percentiles need to be monotonic functions (which they aren't in the example).

The situation $1 < \theta_1 < \theta_2$ is sufficient (or in the different parameterisation from the graph in the answer $1 > \theta_1 > \theta_2$). I used as example the situation $\theta_1 =1$ and $\theta_2 =2$ which satisfies $1 \leq \theta_1 < \theta_2$, but also some examples with $1 > \theta_1$ can work.

actually $1 < \theta_1 < \theta_2$ might not be sufficient. The tipping point where for every  $t< \theta_1 < \theta_2$ the distributions don't dominate each other is the point where the slope of the upper bound $\theta + 1/\theta$ is zero.

Yes. The monotonicity of the sample quantiles indeed is intuitive. That could ensure the estimator preserves the order.
